# void pointer typecasting to pid_t incorrectly

Tags: c, linux, process, multiprocessing

I am having an issue with passing a pid_t by reference as a void pointer, and typecasting it back to a pid_t.  My code is as follows:

```
typedef void * ProcessHandle_t;

void createProcess( ProcessHandle_t * processHandle )
{
    pid_t newTask = fork();

    if( newTask != 0 )
    {
        /* Parent process */
        /* Return a process handle for the main task to use */
        *processHandle = &newTask;
        printf("pid_t output 1: %d\n", *((pid_t *)*processHandle));
    } else
    {
        while(1){
            printf("Child running\n");
        }
    }

}

void deleteProcess( ProcessHandle_t processHandle )
{
    pid_t deleteTask = *((pid_t *)processHandle);

    printf("pid_t output 3: %d\n", deleteTask));

    kill(deleteTask, SIGKILL);
}

int main( )
{
    ProcessHandle_t processHandle;

    createProcess( &processHandle );

    printf("pid_t output 2: %d\n", ((pid_t *)*processHandle));

    deleteProcess( processHandle );

    printf("Parent exiting\n");

}
```

And my output is:

```
pid_t output 1: 19876
pid_t output 2: 19876
pid_t output 3: 493972479
Parent exiting
```

But I have no idea why.  If I do the same kind of dereferencing with ints, it works, but I get a really strange value when I do the same for pid_t.

Is there a specific reason why this does not work with pid_t, but works with other variable types?

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but these sort of headaches are precisely why you shouldn't hide pointer semantics behind a typedef. If your "abstraction" starts breaking your code, it's a bad abstraction.

Comment: Shouldn't `*((pid_t *)processHandle)` be `(pid_t)processHandle` in `deleteProcess`?

Comment: If you're going to the trouble of adding a typedef, why not `typedef ptr_t * ProcessHandle_t;`?  It's arguably both clearer and more maintainable.  Or even better, forget the typedef and forget the indirection ... and just use the original `ptr_t` as-is!

Comment: `pid_t newTask` is a local variable. A reference to that, means?!.. that stack frame is gone when parent returns from it. I think you got lucky in the first print (`pid_t output 2: 19876`), because no other function was called....so that address was still containing that value ..

Comment: Ahh I think you may be right arash, I will fix that and let you know if that fixes it!

Comment: That was it arash! Thanks, too easy to overlook those things and think it is something else when you're tired.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that local variables go out of scope once the function they were defined in returns.

In the `createProcess` function you have

```
*processHandle = &newTask;
```

Here you make `*processHandle` point to the *local variable* `newTask`.

When `createProcess` have returned, the memory previously occupied by the `newTask` variable no longer "exist" (actually it will be reused by the next function call), leaving you with a stray pointer.

Dereferencing this pointer will lead to *undefined behavior*!

If you want to copy the contents of `newTask` using pointers, then you need to allocate memory for the copied value, and actually *copy* the value into the newly allocated memory. And if you allocate memory then you of course have to free it as well.

A simpler solution is to not use pointers at all. Avoiding pointers is usually a very good way to avoid undefined behaviors and crashes in general.